# How can I use Tor from networks whose operators attempt to block Tor use?

Tags: bridge, censorship, pluggable-transports

How can I use Tor from networks whose operators attempt to block Tor use?

For example, I previously used Tor from my school's network to avoid restriction of my Web browsing based on keywords, but now attempts to use Tor on their wireless network are blocked and result in presentation the message "TOR/ULTRASURF DETECTED" being shown to me when I switch to use of a browser without Tor.