# My ISP doesn't even allow OBFS3

Tags: censorship, pluggable-transports, internet-service-provider

My ISP locks me out of the Internet if it detects Tor, and the normal browser redirects to the "TOR DETECTED" page. I then got the pluggable transport and added some bridges that I got from [BridgeDB](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/roadmaps/BridgeDB).

When I start up Tor, it works at home, but when I went to my school's ISP, the message log flashed, and this is what happened.

Here is an example on the error log:

> Oct 01 07:55:10.976 [Warning] We were supposed to connect to bridge 'xx.xx.xx.xx:40872' using pluggable transport 'obfs3', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs3'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.

[image: Screenshot of Vidalia log]

Comment: Please don't leak bridge addresses.  BridgeDB gave them to you, and you making them public can get them blocked faster, easier and more widely.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you've failed to launch `obfsproxy` application. I suggest you to download a fresh copy of [Pluggable Transport](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en#download), [verify it's signature](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en), get some `obfs3` bridges from BridgeDB ([as described here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-can-i-use-tor-from-networks-whose-operators-attempt-to-block-tor-use/182#182)), add them to Vidalia and relaunch PT Bundle.

You may want to [open a ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor) or email `help@rt.torproject.org` if you keep getting that error.

Comment: I reinstalled it, and kept getting that error. What are tickets?

Comment: Go to https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor and read the very first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

If you have time you can contribute collecting information about the censorship that you are suffering. Read the following links where you can find how to do it:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/OONI/censorshipwiki

http://www.cs.kau.se/philwint/pdf/foci2013.pdf

https://ooni.torproject.org/

Basically the idea is to run a program (censorship analyzer) behind a censorship zone to collect data regarding which 'services' from the Tor network are not reachable. The main services who should be tested are: (1) probe to access to the official website (www.torproject.org) (2) try to download the consensus from the Directory Authorities (3) try to connect to the relays and (4) try to connect to the bridges. Later, after executing the previous tests from within a censored zone, the censorship analyzers should create a report and transfer it to some developer's DB.

Comment: yes, I should have time: I have a constant hour and a half every day