# Have some warning in the Tor Log... what does it mean?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm using Tor Brouser Bundle on Mac OS 10.12.1

```
09/11/2016, 03:23:32.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016, 03:23:32.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016, 03:23:32.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
09/11/2016, 03:23:32.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
09/11/2016, 03:23:34.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
09/11/2016, 03:23:34.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
09/11/2016, 03:23:34.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
09/11/2016, 03:23:35.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016, 03:23:35.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016, 03:23:35.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016, 03:23:35.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637 at 154.35.22.11:80) 
09/11/2016, 03:23:35.100 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
09/11/2016, 03:23:35.100 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
09/11/2016, 03:23:42.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 2; recommendation warn; host 8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55 at 154.35.22.10:80) 
09/11/2016, 03:23:42.100 [WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
09/11/2016, 03:23:42.100 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
09/11/2016, 03:23:42.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 3; recommendation warn; host A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239 at 83.212.101.3:50000) 
09/11/2016, 03:23:42.100 [WARN] 3 connections have failed: 
09/11/2016, 03:23:42.100 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
09/11/2016, 03:23:42.100 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
09/11/2016, 03:23:42.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: At a glance, it looks like something is interfering with your connections to the Tor network. You should consider using bridges.

Comment: 09/11/2016, 04:59:47.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 at 194.132.209.185:52977) 
09/11/2016, 04:59:47.400 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
09/11/2016, 04:59:47.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
09/11/2016, 05:01:53.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Comment: 09/11/2016, 05:01:53.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016, 05:01:53.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Comment: I'm try now to use bridges, but it doesn't work... @canonizingi

Comment: Bridges with pluggable transports (obfs4 or meek), to hide the underlying protocol being detectable as Tor.

Comment: where I can get such bridges? @canonizingironize

Comment: the `meek` bridges are already configured in your Tor Browser, otherwise there are other answers like https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-can-i-use-tor-from-networks-whose-operators-attempt-to-block-tor-use/184#184 which explain how to get bridges.